# POSTGRESQL CASE-END CONDITION

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I want to use this case-end block in the postgresql query (the whole script is written in python). But, I run into the below error when I run the query and script with both or separately.

```
AND column_name >= CASE
                       WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN CONVERT(DATE_PART(now(), 'yyyy') || '0101' 
                       else '2017-01-01' 
                   END
```

> error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "else"

How can I fix the query? my mistake is in the case-end block usage? Did anyone experience this before?

Comment: You are missing closing parentheses for DATE_PART and CONVERT.

Comment: The convert() makes no sense and it's missing a closing `)` to begin with. If you want to format a date use `to_char()`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing bracket but still your syntax is incorrect

There can be two cases I can think of from your questions

1. You're getting date format out of current time, in that case use the following snippet

```sql
 column_name >= (CASE WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE '2017-01-01' END)
```

2. If you're getting a year out of current time then use the following code

```
 column_name >= (CASE WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN date_part('year', now()) ELSE '2017' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try debugging it on your own.

```
AND column_name >= CASE
                       WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN CONVERT(DATE_PART(now(), 'yyyy') || '0101' 
                      -- else '2017-01-01' 
                   END
```

Comment out each line and run, see from where the error is coming and then fix it.

As stated in the comments the issue is with the `CONVERT` and the `DATE_PART` part. The count of open braces is not matching with the count of the closed braces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using `date_trunc()` in Postgres:

```
(CASE WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', now())
      ELSE '2017-01-01'::DATE
 END)
```